# Prove that if $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$, $f(a) = g(a) = h(a)$, and $f'(x) = h'(x)$ then $g'(a) = f'(a) = h'(a)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm having difficulty proving a statement from 9.19 problem from Spivak's Calculus. It's asking to prove that a function squeezed in-between two functions that have same initial direction and start from the same point will have the same initial direction too.

Concretely, if for all $x$, $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$, $f(a) = g(a) = h(a)$, and $f'(x) = h'(x)$ prove that $g'(a) = f'(a) = h'(a)$.

Spivak's proof is along these lines: look at the right-hand derivative first, we know that for $\Delta > 0$:

$$ \frac{f(a + \Delta) - f(a)}{\Delta} \le \frac{g(a + \Delta) - g(a)}{\Delta} \le \frac{h(a + \Delta) - h(a)}{\Delta} \tag{1}$$

(since $f(a)=g(a)=h(a)$) and thus as $\Delta \rightarrow 0^+$, $\frac{g(a + \Delta) - g(a)}{\Delta} \rightarrow f'(a) = h'(a)$, as desired.

My problem is that while it makes sense that as the limits from the sides go to an identical value, $\frac{g(a + \Delta) - g(a)}{\Delta}$ needs to go to this value too, I can't prove it.

My attempt: if $h'(a)$ (or $f'(a)$) is the right-hand derivative of $g'(a)$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$ we need to find a $\delta$ s.t. for all $0 < \Delta < \delta$ it holds that $$|\frac{g(a + \Delta) - g(a)}{\Delta} - h'(a)| < \epsilon \tag{2}$$

This is where I get stuck, because the (1) doesn't directly help me, and I don't think I can even break it into cases when $h'(a)$ is $<0$ or $>0$, because the functions might behave "weirdly" around $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. It might be easier if we take a few extra steps.

1. We want to show that $\frac{f(a + \Delta) - f(a)}{\Delta} \leq \frac{g(a + \Delta) - g(a)}{\Delta}$. We are given: $$\begin{cases} f(a+\Delta) &\leq& g(a + \Delta)\\f(a) &=& g(a) \end{cases}$$
   We can just subtract the second from the first, and get that $f(a+\Delta) - f(a) \leq g(a + \Delta) - g(a)$. Now all we need to do is divide by $\Delta$.
2. We do the same with $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$ to show the right-hand part of the inequality.
3. Since the left-most term converges to $f'(a)$ and the right-most term converges to $h'(a)$, and we are told that these are equal, the center term must be equal to these as well. This just follows from the "regular" squeeze theorem (or "sandwich theorem"). The one that does not involve derivatives. We have three functions, one of them lying strictly between the other two. When the outer two meet, all three must meet

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand first two steps, as I mentioned I'm having difficulty proving the third step.

Comment: That just follows from the "regular" squeeze theorem (or "sandwich theorem"). The one that does not involve derivatives.
We have three functions, one of them lying strictly between the other two. When the outer two meet, all three must meet.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, and the proof is pretty simple too. Could you add it to the answer so that I can accept it?